# Integration of $|y|^{-2}$ over the ball $B(0,r)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Can one explain why taking an integral of $\frac 1{|y|}$ over a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of radius $r$ is equal to a constant times $r^2$?

> If $y \in \mathbb{R}^3$, then $$\int_{B(0,r)} \frac{dy}{|y|}=Cr^2$$ 
>   where $C$ is an appropriately chosen constant.

Why is this true?

(This is part of a proof in §12.3.2 of PDE Evans, 2nd edition.)

Comment: For a very direct way, express the integral in spherical coordinates.

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2} \int_0^r \frac 1{\rho} \rho^2 \sin^2 \phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$?

Comment: Right.  Which is a constant times $r^2$.  Also, I think you don't want the $\sin$ squared.

Comment: The $\sin^2 \phi$ is supposed to be part of the Jacobian for the 3D sphere, is it not?

Comment: It's $\sin \theta$.  See the below link.  But even if it were squared, that integral still integrates to a constant times $r^2$.  http://mathinsight.org/triple_integral_change_variable_examples

Comment: Ohh, you're right, the Jacobian for the 3-dimensional sphere is $\rho^2 \sin \phi$. My volume should actually be $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^r \frac 1{\rho} \rho^2 \sin \phi d\rho d\phi d\theta.$$

Comment: @Callus I had another question: How do we establish $$\text{div} \left(\frac{y}{|y|^2}\right) =\frac 1{|y|^2}$$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Directly by taking partial derivatives. It's not that bad if you write it as $|y|^{-2} y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Callus said in comments, this can be done with integration in spherical coordinates. But I would rather avoid spherical coordinates, especially because a similar statement may come up in higher dimensions.

Instead, I would make the change of variables $y=rz$. Then 
$$\int_{B(0,r)} \frac{dy}{|y|}=Cr^2
\int_{B(0,1)} \frac{r^3 dz}{r|z|} = r^2 
\int_{B(0,1)} \frac{dz}{|z|} $$
where $\int_{B(0,1)} \frac{dz}{|z|}$ is a constant that we can call $C$.

Comment: The value $\int_{B(0,1)} \frac{dz}{|z|}$ is a constant despite the fact we have $\frac 1{|z|}$ and $|z|$ can possibly be zero?

Comment: A geometric similarity argument as opposed to the standard, uninspired calculation.  Love this.  (I also prefer this type of reasoning for, e.g., proving the electrostatic field from a uniform plane is independent of distance, over whatever is typically done if it's different.)

Comment: @dragon:  I think the singularity is OK because the areas of spheres of constant $|z|$ decrease as $|z|^2$ near the origin