# Evaluating $\int_{B(0,r)} \frac 1{|x|^{n-1}} dx$ (follow-up on a previous question of mine)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I would like to pose [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806578/evaluating-int-b0r-frac-1xn-dx) better. For now, I would like to compute
$$\int_{B(0,r)} \frac 1{|x|^{n-1}}  dx.$$
I learned from that previous question that this integral converges. So I followed the technique posed by [an answer to a different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315267/integration-of-y-2-over-the-ball-b0-r/1316597#1316597) and set $x=rz$. Then
$$\int_{B(0,r)} \frac 1{|x|^{n-1}}  dx = \int_{B(0;1)} \frac 1{r^{n-1} |z|^{n-1} }r^n dz = r \int_{B(0;1)} \frac 1{|z|^{n-1}} dz = Cr$$
where $C > 0$ is a constant. But I am not sure about the last equality, however. Is it really a constant times a radius?

Comment: Yes, it is. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @T.Bongers $\int_{B(0,1)} \frac 1{|z|^{n-1}} \, dz = C$ is not yet clear to me, but should I nonetheless be able to calculate that integral?

Comment: It's a number that one could compute using the higher-dimensional analogues of polar coordinates.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_{|x| = a} \frac{1}{|x|^{n-1}} d|x| = a^{1-n} \int_{|x| = a}  1 d|x| = a^{1-n} a^{n-1} \int_{|x| = 1}  1 d|x| =  S_1$ where $S_1$ is the surface of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @user1952009 $dx$ is a positive measure, so there cannot be any cancellation. So no, they do not mean $d|x|$.

Comment: @T.Bongers right forget it. but how do you write  the radial change of variable then ? (because it probably reduces to what I tried to write that the integral on surfaces of sphere is constant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a beautiful (in my opinion) formula, that can be derived from the coarea formula (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula)):
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}fdx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left ( \int_{\partial B(0,r))}fdS \right )dr$$
Applying it to the case of n-dimensional ball, we get ($r=|x|$):
$$\int_{B(0,R)}\frac{1}{|x|^{n-1}}dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}fdx=\int_{0}^{R}\left ( \int_{\partial B(0,r))}\frac{1}{r^{n-1}}dS \right )dr=\int_{0}^{R}\frac{1}{r^{n-1}}\left ( \int_{\partial B(0,r))}dS \right )dr=\int_{0}^{R}\frac{1}{r^{n-1}}Cr^{n-1}dr=CR$$

The constant $C=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$.